# UITableView: Resetting Cell Selections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

How can I reset cell selections in a `UITableView`?

**Use case**:

I have a `ViewController` with a `UITableView`. I select a cell and I enter another `View Controller`. When I come back to the `TableViewController`, I still see the selected cell. I would like to reset any selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
override func tableView (tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)
```

You could do the following:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:false)
```